# How to get the last inserted id to insert it to another table?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

My problem is how to get the last inserted id, I want to use that id then insert it to another table, since I have foreign key to another table.

```
Dim insertquery As String = "insert into IndustrialEstablishmentFood_tbl(NameOfEstablishment,Address,EmailAddress,CEO_President,GeneralManager,PollutionControlOfficer,NatureOfBusiness,ContactNumber,NameOfAccreditedWasteHauler,ControlNumber,BrgyClearanceWithCTC,DTI_SEC,ECC,PTO,DP,BFAD,AccreditedWasteHauler,SelfMonitoringReport) values (@NameOfEstablishment,@Address,@EmailAddress,@CEOPresident,@GeneralManager,@PollutionControlOfficer,@NatureOfBusiness,@ContactNumber,@NameOfAccreditedWasteHauler,@ControlNumber,@BrgyClearance,@DTISEC,@ECC,@PTO,@DP,@BFAD,@AccreditedWasteHauler,@SMR)" &
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(insertquery, connection)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameOfEstablishment", NameOfEstablishment.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", EmailAddress.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEOPresident", CEOPresident.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeneralManager", GeneralManager.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PollutionControlOfficer", PollutionControlOfficer.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NatureOfBusiness", NatureOfBusiness.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", ContactNumber.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameOfAccreditedWasteHauler", NameOfAccreditedWasteHauler.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ControlNumber", ControlNumber.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrgyClearance", BrgyClearance.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTISEC", DTISEC.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ECC", ECC.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PTO", PTO.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DP", DP.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BFAD", BFAD.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccreditedWasteHauler", AccreditedWasteHauler.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SMR", SMR.Text)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("Successfully added!", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
clear() 'clear all fields after inserted to database
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=KjyGXZPfJsOc_Qbqj59A&q=How+to+get+the+last+inserted+id+to+insert+it+to+another+table&oq=How+to+get+the+last+inserted+id+to+insert+it+to+another+table&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1463.1463..2751...0.0..0.158.233.1j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....6..0i362i308i154i357.fBSq4w78k7Y&ved=0ahUKEwiTnMacmOLkAhVDTt8KHerHBwgQ4dUDCAc&uact=5) will help.

Comment: The T-SQL `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function will give you the value.  Add a `SELECT` statement onto the end of the `CommandText` to get it via an output parameter.  I won't be writing the code for you though.

Comment: The evils of `.AddWithValue` can be found at http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: Thanks guys for the tips. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 (for Integer based IDs)

```
Dim LASTID
Dim selectquery As String = "SELECT MAX(WHATYOUNAMEYOURID) FROM IndustrialEstablishmentFood_tbl GROUP BY WHATYOUNAMEYOURID" 

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(selectquery , connection)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
LASTID = cmd.ExecuteScalar


MessageBox.Show("ID Found!", LASTID, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Option 2 (Optimal & works with GUID) - Create a return in your query to return **@@IDENTITY**

Comment: glad to have helped! if you find answer helpful, feel free to rate it up :)